# How do I create a dataframe from merging csv files and then create a shiny app based on it?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, shiny, reactive

I have a question which may be stupid, but I just wanted to create my first R shiny app. I was thinking of writing a code in which 2 separate csv files would be read and then combined into a single dataframe. I need to add a couple columns in each dataframe before combining them, as shown in the code. So I thought I could manipulate the data outside of the ui and server and then create the app which would allow the user to select what they want to be plotted on each axis. The first part of the code outside the shiny part works fine and I get the desired combined dataframe. However, when I run the code the dataframe does not seem to be created and as such I end up with an empty interface.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Attached I have a picture of the columns in one of the csv files, the second csv file is similar.

[shop1.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubMZG.png)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

twofiles<-c("shop1.csv","shop2.csv")

shop_list<-lapply(twofiles, read.csv, header=TRUE, sep=",")

shop_list<- lapply(seq_along(shop_list), function(i){

df <- shop_list[[i]]
df<-transform(df,ratio1=price_apples/price_pears)
df<-transform(df,ratio2=price_apples/price_cherries)
df<-transform(df,datano=i)
})

finaldata <- do.call(rbind, shop_list)
finaldata$datano <- factor(finaldata$datano)


ui<-fluidPage(

titlePanel("Shops plots"),

sidebarMenu(

selectInput(inputId = "x", label = "Select x-axis:",
            choices = c("Year"="year","Hour"="hour"), selected="year"),

selectInput(inputId = "y", label = "Select y-axis:",
            choices = c("Ratio 1"="ratio1","Ratio 2"="ratio2"),selected="ratio1"),

mainPanel(
  plotOutput("plot")
)
)
)


server<-function(input, output) {


output$plot <-renderPlot({

ggplot(finaldata, aes(x=input$x, y=input$y, group=datano, color = datano)) +
  geom_line()

})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: (1) If the datasets load fine on the console but not in the shiny app, make sure the working directory is correct. I don't know if "running shiny" for you means `shiny::runApp` or deploying to shinyapps.io or similar. (2) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply and I apologise for the image-I am new on here and I will definitely keep this in mind. As for the wd, it seems to be ok and by running shiny I meant the first option. I was wondering if the issue had to do with reactivity or something similar, but I cannot pinpoint what it is still. Does it look like a reasonable way of building the app e.g. building a dataframe before the ui and then working from there in the server?

Comment: The work is not being done inside a `reactive` or `observe` block, or even within the server function, so I have a hard time believing that the issue is related to shiny *directly*.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to get the full code to run?  I had tried to manipulate/combine the datasets directly within the server function (without using reactive as I haven't yet completely grasped it, but by just pasting the code before the ui there), but that definitely did not work.

Comment: You have to use `aes_string` not `aes` if you code it the way you have. Then you should do dataframe manipulation including loading etc.. at the server side. one more thing is that `group=datano` and `color=datano` may prone to the problem also. Try here `yourdataframe$datano`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for comments:

Here is the example code with the `mtcars` dataset:

You have to use `aes_string` not `aes` in `ggplot`.

Dataframe manipulation including loading etc.. should be done server side.

One more thing is that `group=datano` and `color=datano` may prone to the problem also. Try here `yourdataframe$datano`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui<-fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("XXX"),
  
  sidebarMenu(
    
    selectInput(inputId = "x", label = "Select x-axis:",
                choices = c("mpg"="mpg","disp"="disp"), selected="mpg"),
    
    selectInput(inputId = "y", label = "Select y-axis:",
                choices = c("hp"="hp","drat"="drat"),selected="hp"),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server<-function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$plot <-renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(finaldata, aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y, group=mtcars$cyl, color = mtcars$cyl)) +
      geom_line()
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: I posted just after you  ... since `aes_string` is soft-deprecated, if you take on the portion about quasi-quotation (`!!enquo(input$x)`), I'll happily delete mine in favor of this.

Comment: Thank you dear @r2evans. Please leave your answer/explanation, This is great as always!!!

Comment: Thank you both so much, I would never have thought that this was the issue. Both of your answers were very helpful and informative and indeed it worked this time. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem you're having has nothing to do with the frame, but with programmatic use of `ggplot2`. In general, look up `ggplot2` and `quasiquotation` and you'll find yourself in a quagmire of NSE (non-standard evaluation) mechanisms that you thought you'd never need (or never knew you would need, to be honest).

I can replicate some non-workingness with this simple non-shiny example.

```r
library(ggplot2)
input <- list(x = "mpg", y = "disp")
```

This produces the wrong chart, just a single point:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point()
```

But if you switch to this, it should work:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=!!sym(input$x), y=!!sym(input$y))) + geom_point()
```

That is, using `!!sym(input$x)` instead of just `input$x` (and for anything else you will be placing within `aes(...)`.

If you're curious, the older (soft-deprecated) solution would have been to use `aes_string`, which still works (but I don't know for how long):

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point()
```

---

Side note:

- I think it'd be a bit more direct (and code-golf simpler) to read in your data as:

  ```r
  twofiles <- setNames(nm = c("shop1.csv","shop2.csv"))
  shop_list <- lapply(twofiles, read.csv, header=TRUE, sep=",")
  finaldata <- transform(
    dplyr::bind_rows(shop_list, .id = "datano"),
    ratio1 = price_apples/price_pears,
    ratio2 = price_apples/price_cherries,
    datano = factor(datano)
  )
  ```

  Though since you're already pulling in all of `tidyverse`, you might as well switch to the `dplyr`-methods ... not that it buys you a lot here.

Comment: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=.data[[input$x]], y=.data[[input$y]])) + geom_point()` is also valid.